# Dropbox, where did my pictures go? Disappeared!

Tags: dropbox

I uploaded a bunch of pics from my android device to dropbox, and every single one of the pictures and videos that I uploaded are now missing from my phone! How do I get my pictures back and delete this horrible app without losing my stuff? Theyre pictures of my son

Comment: Have you tried logging in to dropbox.com to see if your stuff's there?

Comment: It would also help if you can tell *how* you uploaded your pics (which app you used, e.g.). This would make it easier to determine what happened and possibly tell you how to avoid the problem in the future.